# Value Substitution in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to figure out how I can change the existing values of my data frame. I've included a quick outline below and thanks for your help!!

**Here's what I currently have:**

```
company      top_ten_advertiser
'Company A'         'Is Top 10'
'Company B'         'Is Top 10'
'Company C'         'Is Top 10'
'Company D'         'Is Top 10'
…              …
'Company X'        'Not Top 10'
'Company Y'        'Not Top 10'
'Company Z'        'Not Top 10'
```

**I want to change to the following:**

```
   company      top_ten_advertiser
'Company A'       'Top 10 Company'
'Company B'       'Top 10 Company'
'Company C'       'Top 10 Company'
'Company D'       'Top 10 Company'
…              …
'Company X'   'Not Top 10 Company'
'Company Y'   'Not Top 10 Company'
'Company Z'   'Not Top 10 Company'
```

Comment: if 'top_ten_advertiser' is a factor, just change the levels of it. If it is a character variable, do string substitution or matching. If you don't know what a factor is, then rewind, learn some basic R, try some things, then get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data frame is called df. Do this for a character variable:

```
# Add the word "Company" to all values of top_ten_advertiser
df$top_ten_advertiser = paste(df$top_ten_advertiser, "Company", sep=" ")
# Remove the "Is " from "Is Top 10"
df$top_ten_advertiser = gsub("Is ", "", df$top_ten_advertiser)
```

Or this for a factor variable:

```
# Install the plyr package if you haven't already done so using 
# install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
revalue(df$top_ten_advertiser, 
        c("Is Top 10"="Top 10 Company", "Not Top 10"="Not Top 10 Company"))
```

If you find it painful to change levels of a factor, you can convert the factor variable to character first, change the values, and then convert back to a factor, like this:

```
df$top_ten_advertiser = as.character(df$top_ten_advertiser)
df$top_ten_advertiser = paste(df$top_ten_advertiser, "Company", sep=" ")
df$top_ten_advertiser = gsub("Is ", "", df$top_ten_advertiser)
df$top_ten_advertiser = factor(df$top_ten_advertiser)
```

And, just for completeness, since Matthew Lundberg mentioned doing this with a regular expression:

```
tst$top_ten_advertiser = gsub("(Is )?(.*)", "\\2 Company", tst$top_ten_advertiser)
```

It's parsimonious, but cryptic if you're new to regular expressions. This will work on a character or factor variable. However, doing this on a factor variable will convert it to character.

Comment: You're just adding 'company'.  You didn't remove the 'Is '.

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for your comment and added a few other options.

Comment: Changing the levels of a factor is much easier then string substitution if there aren't too many levels. Just do `levels(myfactor) <- thenewlevels`.

Comment: @Roland, isn't that somewhat prone to error, because you have to make sure you put the new levels in the same order as the original ones? I like `revalue` from `plyr` because you have to explicitly map each old value to the desired new value, which seems safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$top_ten_advertiser <- gsub("Is Top 10", "Top 10 Company", df$top_ten_advertiser)
```

Comment: And you missed the "Not" substitution.  You can get both with one regular expression.

Comment: I figured it was extensible.